# File uploading with PHP: Need it to retain extension

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have written a script to upload a file and store the path in a database table so it be downloaded. I have the following code:

```
 <?php require("includes.php");
 ?><!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php if(isset($_FILES["upload"])==TRUE)
 {
      $errors           = array();
      $excluded      = array("exe", "zip", "js", "msi");
      /* If the contents of the file are to be held in the database then checking the extension is somewhat unneccessary but, hey, lets get rid of the files we know we don't want and then check the mime type. */
      $name               = $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
      $size               = $_FILES["upload"]["size"];     
      $type               = $_FILES["upload"]["type"];
      $temp               = $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];     
      $extension = explode(".", $name);
      $extension = end($extension);
      if(in_array($extension, $excluded)==TRUE)
      {
           $errors[] ="This file may not be uploaded";
      }
      if(empty($errors)==FALSE)
      {
           foreach($errors as $error)
           {
                echo "<p>{$error}</p>\n";
           }
      }
      else
      {
           $year = date("Y");
           $month = date("m");
           $day = date("d");
           $name = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "_", $name));
           $path = "uploads/{$day}-{$month}-{$year}";
           if(file_exists($path)==FALSE)
           {
                mkdir($path);
           }
           elseif(file_exists("{$path}/{$name}")==FALSE)
           {
                move_uploaded_file($temp, "{$path}/{$name}");
                $add = add_file_to_database($connection, "{$path}/{$name}");
                if($add[0]==TRUE)
                {
                     $url = "http://example.com/uploads.php?id={$add[1]}";
                     echo "<p>This file has been uploaded, it can be found at: <a href=\"{$url}\">{$url}</a></p>";
                }
                else
                {
                     echo "<p>I'm sorry but an error happened</p>";
                }
           }
      }
 }
 ?>
 <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="upload">Upload a file: </label><input type="file" name="upload" id="upload"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The code in uploads.php is:

```
 <?php require("includes.php");
 $file = get_uploaded_file($connection, $_GET["id"]);
 header("Content-Type:{$file[0]}");
 echo file_get_contents($file[1]);
 ?>
```

If I upload a jpeg file, a PDF or txt file then it displays in the browser as I want it to do but if I upload a word file or a MP3 then I want it to download as the normal file instead of being uploads.php

Not sure how I am going to achieve this. Can you give me some ideas as to how I do this so if I upload "demo.mp3" and I get an ID of 1 then I want it to download a file entitled "demo.mp3". Just thinking that MS Word doesn't recognise its own MIME type

Comment: [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-examples) should provide you with all you need, since the *first example* does exactly that. also, you should consider moving your upload-dir outside of your document root and/or disallowing all file suffixes related to PHP, because an attacke could upload his own script, execute it and by doing so, **compromise your whole server**.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann do you have any good reference about the "compromise your whole server" thing? I' ve been working with file uploading lately and that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Tony what do you mean by "good reference"? it's quite simple: attacker uploads a file "evil.php" with `<?php echo file_get_contents('supersecretfile.php'); exec("evilsystemcommand");`, access it via browser and -boom- he's in.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I don't know the command "exec", i am looking at it right now. The "supersecretfile.php" i guess it it is a file in my server, which through that command(file_get_contents) can read it as html right?